# How to error handle in fetchMore pagination?

Tags: apollo-client

Im trying to use fetchMore with react-infinite-scroll (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller). It works most of the times, but I want to be able to catch a server error and handle it. I am talking to a service that 'throttles' me a lot so what I want to do is I wait 1sek and I try again.

My problem is that I don't know where to handle the error if it's thrown in fetchMore, since it's not passed into the render function.

I have tried using try/catch on the fetchMore function itself, I did not catch the error.

Im using nextjs if that helps.

```
return (
    <Query query={GET_COLLECTION} variables={{ handle: collectionHandle, first: 10, orderBy: orderBy }}>
        {({ loading, error, data, fetchMore, refetch }) => {
            if (loading && !data.getCollection) return <CollectionListLoader />
            // Normally I refetch in handleError
            if (error) return handleError({ error, loader: <Loader fullscreen={true} type="logo" />, refetch })

            const collection = data.getCollection

            return (
                <InfiniteScroll
                    initialLoad={false}
                    loadMore={() => {
                        fetchMore({
                            query: GET_MORE_COLLECTION,
                            variables: { handle: collectionHandle, first: 10, after: collection.products[collection.products.length - 1].cursor, orderBy: orderBy },
                            updateQuery: appendQuery,
                        })
                    }}
                    hasMore={collection.productsHasNextPage}
                    loader={<Loader type="logo" key="loader" />}
                >
                    <div className="row">
                        {collection.products.map((p, i) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="col-6 col-md-4" key={i}>
                                    <Product product={p} collectionHandle={collectionHandle} />
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
                </InfiniteScroll>
            )
        }}
    </Query>
)
```

Actual: If an error is thrown in fetchMore, the infinite scroller loads indefinetly, and I cant handle the error

Expected: If an error is thrown in fetchMore, I catch it and can handle it

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't appear to be documented by Apollo but `fetchMore` returns a promise so you can handle errors with `.catch()`.